uiautomatorviewer missing from Android Studio Koala Feature Drop for Windows
I'm new to Android development. I have been following some tutorial that relied on uiautomatorviewer to inspect different visual elements of Android application. My Android Studio installation doesn't have uiautomatorviewer.
I had downloaded an Android Studio 2024.1.2.12 Koala Feature Drop installer package from https://developer.android.com/studio, installed it and then launched it and installed Android API 35 and 12 for my own device, Android SDK Build-tools 35, Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest) and Android SDK Platform-tools. Every tutorial that mentions uiautomatorviewer, including the one I've been following, says it should be located in SDK-tools directory, which on my system should translate to C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools (username obfuscated). There is no such directory on my computer. I only have build-tools, cmdline-tools and platform-tools under SDK, among other directories that don't have tools in the name. Searching C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ for uiautomatorviewer yields nothing. There is a notice on developer.android.com that SDK Tools have been deprecated in 2017 and replaced by SDK Command-line Tools which I have installed but they don't have uiautomatorviewer. The article on UI Automator testing which has been updated in July 2024 still mentions uiautomatorviewer. I have found several similar questions on Stackoverflow and some relevant tutorials online, but they all deal with a much older version of Android Studio which includes SDK Tools, so nothing has worked for me so far. I tried re-installing Android Studio after deleting all the related files, including C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Android multiple times, tried installing an older version 2024.1.1.13 and tried downloading Android Studio as a zip archive and launching it from there.
Question is, is uiautomatorviewer still available for Android Studio 2024.1.2.12 Koala Feature Drop? If so, how can I get it?
